# Load laravel data table when submitting search field

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm new to laravel. I have UI design of search box. When I search search-term it will show data under the search box as a table. Initially it's only shows search box. How can I handle that kind of situation with laravel? [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNgt8.png)

Comment: You can do with Laravel Livewire Search

Answer (score 0):

As @xNoJustice already said you can include a search package.
If you want to do it by yourself you are able to query each field of your Model for the search word.

For example you can search the Models like:

```
Model::where('xxx','LIKE','%'.$search_word.'%')
->orWhere('yyy','LIKE','%'.$search_word.'%')->get();
```

You will need to do this for each Model you want to be searched tḧrough and then pass all the results to your view.